# KotlinJvmOptions useIR option

Tags: kotlin

Starting from 1.3.70 EAP, there is a new option in

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinJvmOptions
```

Which is

```
var useIR: kotlin.Boolean
```

And which activates

```
-Xuse-ir
```

(see https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/commit/383239aff62ad353fa5e9a927003d7973e4565be)

This option seems not described in the documentation. What does it do? What are the implications? I notice a decreased build size (in the KB order tho).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This option enables the new implementation of the JVM compiler back-end, the part that generates the bytecode for the JVM, in the Kotlin compiler.

As of Kotlin 1.3.71, it's not production-ready yet, and the flag has been added for internal testing, so please don't use it for any real-life projects just yet.

Comment: Thanks! I suggest you put a couple lines in the docs to say one should not use it.

Comment: I saw that Android Studio now adds the option by default, does this means it's production-ready now?

Comment: @dnhyde the JVM IR is now stable since February, and the JS IR is in beta.